# How to properly encode links to external URL in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

This view suppose to show  a list of hyperlinks, each pointing to an external URL. The goal is for the user to click one of these links and have their browser open a new tab with the selected URL.
Currently I have the following markup:

```
@Html.ActionLink("SomeSite", "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/SomeSite")
```

This markup produces:

```
http://localhost:58980/AccessInstance/http%3a/subdomain.mydomain.com/SomeSite
```

instead of :

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/SomeSite
```

What can I change in my markup to make this work as I expect?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't need to use `@Html.ActionLink` for that. Just use a plain A tag:

```
<a href="http://subdomain.mydomain.com/SomeSite">SomeSite</a>
```

`Html.ActionLink` is specifically for generating links to actions defined in MVC controllers, *in the same app*. Since you're linking to an absolute URL, you don't need any of the functionality that `Html.ActionLink` provides.

Comment: Hello I call the url from a database field and I need to be link.
I call the data in my view 
 `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Announcment_Link)` how can I make it to be a link

Comment: Additionally, if you generate the href from an entity property, MVC will generate an action URL unless the address specifies the http protocol ie: http://stackoverflow.com vs www.stackoverflow.com . So make sure that you got that http in your data if you want an external url.

Answer (score 16):

Two ways :

**1.** update the database column with full link:

eg `SQL`:

```
update ProductTable set ProductLink='http://www.example.com/Product/Mobiles' where ID=123
```

**In asp mvc view**

```
<a href="@model.ProductLink">View</a>
```

**2.** Hardcode the `http` part and list from model

```
<a href="http://@model.ProductLink">View</a>
```

Hope helps someone.

Comment: When I use
`<a href="http://@model.ProductLink">View</a>`
it removes the : from http

Comment: @touinta, some browser dont show up the protocol check [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/09/28/firefox-add-http-back-to-address-bar/) article , may i know how you store the example link in your database column ?

Comment: @storm In the database the Link field is varchar. Some of them are with http://www and other are with www.

Comment: why dont you store with `http://` ? then it would be easy, check my answer for your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33053393/2218697) and comment there.

Answer (score 0):

While a ViewBag is overused and not the best choice most of the time this is something that I had done when inheriting someone else's mvc app to do a quick fix for a URL that I needed to redirect to with a specific dynamically changing querystring parameter

```
  <a target="_parent" href="http://localhost:56332/services/@ViewBag.factory">View Service</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET Core 6

This seems to be the most correct answer:

```cs
 <a href=@item.Url target="_blank">Link</a>
```

This will generate the following result:

[image]

As you can see at the bottom left corner of the window before clicking the link, the URL address was rendered as it is (NOTE: The cursor was recorded out of place for some reason, that's a ShareX problem, ignore it).

Than link will be directly saved as a `nvarchar(750)` type (probably any character like type will do the work). No changes to the original link were made before saving it or on reading:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to take into account your RouteConfiguration.

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}"

because you are specifying the action link as the entire link that you want to redirect.
I would recommend that you use the @rossipedia answer because you can make tricky things like putting a span inside the link

Answer (score -1):

Here to display link that are clickable in index page

```
     <td>         
        @Html.ActionLink(item.FileName, "../Uploads/Catalogue/"+item.FileName)
    </td>
```