# Insert a link to a db field mvc 5

Tags: hyperlink

I have a field to my db which is external link and one that is a file. I need to display these fields to my view.
I have this code where I call my data.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.announcement_Link)
```

and for the file

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.announcement_Uploaded_File)
```

It brings the url and the file name . How can I make the 1st to be a link and the second to be linked to the file and to be downloaded?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

**In Database :**

**1.** For A Link:

eg `SQL`:

```
update AnnouncementTable set announcement_Link='http://www.example.com/Announcement/All'
where ID=123
```

**2.** For A Downloadable Link: (Note: saving uploaded file link with filename in column like:)

```
update AnnouncementTable set announcement_Uploaded_File='http://www.example.com/Announcement/
download/filename' where ID=123
```

**In asp mvc view**

**1.** For A Link:

```
<a href="@model.announcement_Link">View</a>
```

**2.** For A Downloadable Link:

```
<a href="@model.announcement_Uploaded_File">View</a>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: My database has a lot of records already with `http://` The only records which work are they without `http://` I try the `<a href="http://@model.announcement_Link">View</a>` but it returns the path with `locahost:xxxx/www.mylink.com`